# Return specific item in array Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, char

I have an array of chars:

```
["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"]
```

I only want to return `["EF"]`

How can I enter a String and a number and have it return the element at that point in the array of chars?

E.g.

```
showMe :: String -> Int -> String
```

Comment: [String] (list of string) is not same as array of chars.

Answer (score 5):

You need `(!!)`, the index operator.

```
["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"] !! 2 == "EF"
```

But the correct signature is `[String] -> Int -> String` in this case (altough `(!!)` is more generic: `[a] -> Int -> a`)